# What is the name of this peppermint stick candy?

Tags: candy, texture

I've had a hard time finding information online about peppermint candy sticks that are hard, but porous and brittle - the peppermint sticks of my youth. I believe the commercially available brand that is what I'm thinking of is King Leo peppermint stick.

What I'm looking for is different from hard/glossy/sticky candy canes, and would not be chewy/soft candy/taffy either.

Does anyone know what it is called?

Comment: I do not know these sticks you mention, but you might find recipes if you Google "hard foam candy"? If you mean the kind of fairly hard, dense, but foamy candy I have in mind, then maybe you could find something.

Comment: I think what you mean is called *schuimpjes* in Dutch. But that word can also mean little meringues, which are far more fluffy than what you mean. So you might Google for recipes for "schuimpjes Sinterklaas": in connection with the holiday of Sinterklaas, you're more likely to get the dense kind of schuimpjes. An example that I think is the right kind: http://heerlijke-recepten.blogspot.nl/2012/12/basis-snoep-schuimpjes-in-4-smaken.html In that recipe, the schuimpjes are not baked, but *dried* over several days, to arrive at the right consistency.

Comment: I saw on another page that "heavy" schuim is made by heating eggwhite and sugar au bain marie, or even hotter, while whisking to get it somewhat foamy. But I suspect some gelatine is also needed. The ingredients at this supermarket are mainly sugar, syrup, water, gelatine. https://www.ah.nl/producten/product/wi374843/ah-schuimbanaantjes#ingredienten

Comment: I know the candy you are talking about. They are called sugar sticks or soft sugar sticks. They are not shiny like candy canes. And while the sticks are hard, they break easily and melt away quickly in your mouth. Bob's and King Leo are available online, but I've never seen a recipe for making them. (Note that recipe requests are off topic here.) My favorite is the plain sugar variety (very hard to find), but the peppermint is good, too.

Comment: @Cerberus Thank you! Those Dutch schuimpjes don't look exactly right but could just be the shape. I will check them out

Comment: @Cindy Thank you for the additional names to check out, that will help me research. "Dull" texture and brittle/melty are exactly right, maybe I can find them online under those names.

Comment: Glad to help! I see there's a vote to close (recipe request) so I'm going to edit your post slightly.

Answer (score 1):

I also know the difference between peppermint sticks and candy canes (which is the terminology I've always used), but part of the problem is that names vary a lot by region.

Candy canes and peppermint sticks begin similarly: you cook sugar until very hot - at least 270 F, if not more depending on the recipe. The first difference between the two is that peppermint sticks will likely remain on the lower edge, while candy canes will likely go a little over 300 F. The lower the temperature, the softer your final product will be. Peppermint sticks are also liable to contain butter to add to that melt-in-your-mouth texture. Once the sugar syrup has come to temp, you remove from the heat, pour onto a marble slab (or other work surface). From there you can add and stir in flavors and colors.

The second and biggest difference is in how the sugar syrup is worked. For candy canes, the sugar syrup is pulled to develop that white, opaque and shiny characteristic. (Check out Hercules Candy or Lofty Pursuits on YouTube to see it done.) For peppermint sticks, like classic fondant or fudge, the sugar syrup is deliberately worked until they crystallize, becoming opaque and not-shiny.

EDIT: Having learned more about candy since I originally answered this, another massive difference is that candy canes are likely made with additional glucose syrup, which inhibits crystallization. Peppermint sticks should be made with just sucrose, which will almost certainly crystallize after being pulled, even if it isn't visibly occurring by the end of the pulling process.

Candy canes and peppermint sticks are both pulled into shape once the sugar syrup has been appropriately prepared. Candy canes get a crook while sticks are left straight.

I managed to find an [example recipe](https://www.griswoldhomecare.com/worcester/blog/2015/november/home-care-recipes-homemade-soft-peppermint-stick/)for soft peppermint sticks as well which describes the procedure/appearance, which might be helpful.

That said, a final note is that candy-making in general takes a lot more skill than is often (or easily) communicated, and pulling candy is honestly difficult to do at all, let alone so it looks good. Just be careful with any hot sugar syrup and do plenty of research before you start trying to pull or work anything capable of burning you.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a bit like "Edinburgh Rock" which (used to) be available as 4 inch sticks in various flavours of a hard sugar confection with a texture not unlike a stick of chalk.
Similar but harder is coltsfoot rock but as far as I know only coltsfoot flavour.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

https://www.giambris.com/Porous-Peppermint-Sticks-1-Doz_p_1810.html

Porous seems to be a potential keyword, you might also browse through “old fashioned” candies or candy sticks for familiar brands or descriptions, especially since you do seem to be searching for something previously common but not currently… in fashion i suppose.  I remembered this one while looking for a different “old fashioned” candy a while ago and just remembered it when i saw your question.

Answer (score 0):

Virginia Beauty Brand sugar stick candy!

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, a single line answer is not very explanatory.